# Polygons from a raster within an elevation range

Tags: qgis, dem, elevation, terrain

In the image below I have generated some isolines starting from the terrain model and I have filtered them within a certain elevation range 800 - 1500m of elevation in QGIS.

But I would like to make polygons of these areas drawn in blue.
[image]

Comment: Have you seen the *Contours (polygons)* tool? That will probably help you.

Comment: yes QGis but it produce lines

Comment: It shouldnt. Make sure you are selecting [contour polygons](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rasterextraction.html#contour-polygons) and not contour

Comment: However I start only from a raster

Comment: @matt what is "Contours (polygons) tool" ??? a qgis plugin?

Comment: It is a GDAL tool native to QGIS. *Processing toolbox -> GDAL -> Raster extraction -> Contour Polygons*.

Comment: You're to lazy to click the link i provided.... It clearly states "Extracts contour polygons from any GDAL-supported elevation raster."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using standard Qgis Contour that is a front end to gdal_contour utility.
The solution to draw polygons instead lines is to add these parameters in addition to the command line, -amin -amax is the range of elevation values to draw.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you could use this workflow:

1. You need to translate your Line-Geometry to a Polygon-Geometry. You could use a buffer with a very small buffersize for this. If you habe more than one Ring in the Layer you can buffer just a selected Line. Perhaps there is a better solution for this step.
2. Now you can use the Tool deleteholes. Just select the buffer as Input and start the tool.

This workflow will just work for full rings. So it wouldnt work for the red lines in your example untill you "complete" manually the line-geometries to rings.

Comment: Remember that I'm start from a raster, the isolines Is not required, It's only my first attempt. I think there must be a simpler solution.